# how to get the nearest decade/century/millenium with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

im trying to find a way to get the 2 nearest ranges of a date could be decade , century, millenium

Example

```
var date = new Date() // Mon Jul 09 2018 17:12:17 GMT-0400
date.getDecadeRange() // [Jan 01 2010 , Dec 31 , 2019]
```

And so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this question always pops up . Its funny. 
Anyway i been reading the date api from MDN but i cant think of a way to do it.
Sorry

Comment: There's an answer already but I'd just like to point out that this decade started on Jan 1 2011 and not 2010 (because there was no year zero). Similarly 21st century started on Jan 1 2001.

Comment: @TimSim—that's one issue that can only be sorted by business rules. Some think 2000 was the last year of the 20th century, but popular culture says it was the first year of the 21st century. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To round to the closest multiple we might use small utility:

```
 const round = (n, to) => n - n % to;
```

Now we just have to round the years, and take the first day:

```js
const round = (n, to) => n - n % to;

const now = new Date();

const start = new Date(round(now.getFullYear(), 100), 0, 1);
// Go to the start of the next period ...
const end = new Date(round(now.getFullYear(), 100) + 100, 0, 1);
end.setDate(end.getDate() - 1); // then go one day back

console.log(`${start}\n${end}`);
```

Comment: You can save a line by setting the end directly with a day of 0: `new Date(round(now.getFullYear(), 100) + 100, 0, 0)`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone who answered. 
reading the jonas answer i had a momento and it came up to me the answer

```
const dateRanges = (date, rule, sum = 0) 
      => Math.floor(date.getFullYear() / rule) * rule + sum
```

And i can execute it in this way

```
const lowerDecade  = dateRanges(new Date() , 10 /** => decade**/)
const upperDecade  = dateRanges(new Date() , 10 /** => decade**/, 9)
```